# Sqlite: Get Modal/Mode from two related columns

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is an extract from the table GAMES:

```
ID  WUSER       BUSER
1   ddyer       bdot
2   ddyer       ronaldinho
3   bluedog     ronaldinho
4   ronaldinho  bluedog
5   bluedog     ronaldinho
6   ddyer       bobc
7   bobc        ddyer
```

The table is a database from the website boardspace.net in which people play board games. In the database wuser and buser are for white and black players, and id is the game played. Now I want to know the players that played the most. So I do this for white players:

```
 SELECT wuser, count(wuser) 
 FROM game 
 GROUP BY wuser 
 ORDER BY count(wuser) DESC;
```

RESULT IS:

```
wuser    count(wuser)
Dumbot   75926
guest    22541
image13  1594
DrRaven  1460
Eucalyx  1147
Loizz    963
```

Then I have to do the same for black players:

```
 SELECT buser, count(buser) 
 FROM game 
 GROUP BY buser 
 ORDER BY count(buser) DESC;

buser    count(buser)
Dumbot   59489
guest    29324
Eucalyx  1007
image13  756
DrRaven  746
Loizz    715
alexis   660
```

I can sum it manually as I did below, but how do I get the result from a single SQL statement:

```
user     count(as both buser and wuser)
Dumbot   135412
guest    51865
image13  2350
DrRaven  2206
```

I just want know the total number of games played for each player, I am not interested whether they play white or black.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you got a large number of rows per user you better COUNT before the UNION and add another aggregate step:

```
SELECT usr, sum(cnt)
FROM
 (
   SELECT wuser as usr, count(*) as cnt
   FROM game 
   GROUP BY wuser

   UNION ALL

   SELECT buser, count(*) 
   FROM game 
   GROUP BY buser
 ) AS dt
 GROUP BY usr
 ORDER BY sum(cnt) DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` to unpivot your table. Then just `GROUP BY` username and `COUNT`:

```
SELECT usr, COUNT(usr)
FROM (
   SELECT WUSER AS usr 
   FROM GAMES

   UNION ALL

   SELECT BUSER AS usr 
   FROM GAMES ) u
GROUP BY usr
ORDER BY COUNT(usr) DESC
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/e2fba/4)